# Writing completion block with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Estimote's iOS SDK and I'm trying to write the following Objective-C code in Swift:

```
 [self.beaconConnection writeMajor:newMajor completion:^(unsigned short major, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error major write: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }

            self.majorTextFiled.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", major];
        }];
```

I'm struggling with getting the completion block to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
beaconConnection.writeMajor(major, completion: { value, error in

            }
        )
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing? This looks like a fine start.

Comment: Ahh I just realized it's because major should be UInt16, and I had it as regular Int.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally had major as Int and it's supposed to be UInt16 for that method.
Here's the updated code:

```
beaconConnection.writeMajor(UInt16(major), completion: { value, error in

            }
        )
```